# SQOOP - how to do a multi table or selective table import in sqoop from MYSQL

Tags: sqoop

how to do a **multi table** or **selective table** *import* in sqoop from MYSQL

I can see either we can import table by table or import-all-tables.
am looking for a way to import only certain tables from MYSQL.

Any help would be appreciated ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to put multiple tables in sqoop import command.

---

But you can use `import-all-tables` with `--exclude-tables <tables>` to exclude some tables while importing all the tables of a database.

**For example**

You have 5 tables *(tbl1, tbl2, tbl3, tbl4, tbl5)* in `testdb` database and you want to exclude tbl2 and tbl4.

Use the following command:

`sqoop import-all-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb --exclude-tables tbl2,tbl4 .....`